# Allow user for SSH in web root

Tags: ssh, debian

I have a setup for nginx which has always worked well. I can create different users with multiple websites. (Debian 11)

For this I use the following commands

```
useradd -m myuser
mkdir -p /var/www
chmod -R 555 /var/www
mkdir -p /var/www/webuser
chown root:root /var/www/webuser

useradd webuser
usermod webuser -s /bin/false
usermod webuser -d /var/www/webuser

mkdir -p /var/www/webuser/html
mkdir -p /var/www/webuser/logs
chmod 750 /var/www/webuser/html
chmod 750 /var/www/webuser/logs

chown -R webuser:www-data /var/www/webuser/html
chown -R webuser:www-data /var/www/webuser/logs
chmod -R g+s /var/www/webuser/html

groupadd sftpGroup
usermod -a -G sftpGroup webuser
```

This is not yet a sshd_conf

```
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp
Match Group sftpGroup
    ChrootDirectory %h
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
    AllowTcpForwarding no
    X11Forwarding no
```

Is there a way to make the user webuser SSH access to his directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible, first we need to change the shell for `webuser` `usermod webuser -s /bin/bash` then go to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and modifify accordingly:

```
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp

# For SFTP access with chroot
Match Group sftpGroup
    ChrootDirectory %h
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
    AllowTcpForwarding no
    X11Forwarding no

# For SSH access
Match Group sshGroup
    AllowTcpForwarding yes
    X11Forwarding no
```

then create a new Group `groupadd sshGroup` then `usermod -a -G sshGroup webuser` then restart ssh `systemctl restart ssh` and it should work